# Limiting validation to the create page not the edit page

Tags: php, drupal-6

What is the best way to limit your custom validation check to the add page and not the edit page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) function to check that you're on the /node/add/... page. Try changing the first line inside your hook_form_alter implementation to read...

```
if($form_id === 'external_favourite_node_form' && arg(1) == 'add') {
```